# Match the string using regex

Tags: regex, shell

I have few files like `123.iso`, `234.isoaa`, `456.isoab`, `sajdhsjf.isoaf`.
I want to extract all the files except those that end with exactly `.iso`.
For example, I should have `234.isoaa`, `456.isoab`, `sajdhsjf.isoaf`.

Comment: This question is not defined clearly enough and would profit a lot from a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), clarifying what part of your code isn't working as expected. `shell` is rather imprecise, too. Which shell?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you meant *"all the files **with suffix beginning with .iso** except those..."*, this works:

```
ls -1 | egrep "\.iso.+"
```

Comment: This would not list file such as `foo.bar`. Maybe this is what the OP really wants, but he says that he wants to extract **all**files except those ending in `.iso`. If he really means this, the grepping solution would be `ls -1|grep -v '\.iso$'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

\b[\w]*(?!.iso\b).[\w]*\b

Answer (score 0):

As Tim Pietzker noted, you didn't say for which shell you need a solution, but in zsh you could do

```
setopt local_options extended_glob
echo *^*.iso(N)
```

If you are happy to get **only** files which have `.isoX` at the end (with any X), this should work in bash, zsh and ksh:

```
echo *.iso?*
```

Note that this second solution - different to the first one - would **not** list files such as `abc.txt`.

Of course you can do a `ls -1` instead of the `echo`. This depends on how you what you want to do with the result.